# Вывод DateTime в DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Имеется класс `MyTable`, состоящий из нескольких свойств,включая `DateTime date`
Также имеется массив `MyTable[] data;`
В него я подгружаю данные из файла:

```
data =
            File.ReadLines(path,
                System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding(1251))
            .Select(x => x.Split(' '))
            .Select(x => new MyTable
            {
                date = Convert.ToDateTime(x[0]),
                ...
                ...
            })
            .ToArray();
```

При выводе данных в таблицу: `grid.ItemsSource = data;`
таблица выводит свойство `DateTime date` в следующем формате: `8/14/2017 12:00:00 AM`
Можно ли выводит эту дату в другом формате, например `dd/mm/yyyy`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В шаблоне столбца `DataGrid` укажите маску `StringFormat`, например:

```
<DataGrid ...>
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        ...
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дата"
                            Binding="{Binding date, StringFormat=dd/MM/yyyy}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: выводит ошибку: Необработанное исключение типа "System.InvalidOperationException" в PresentationFramework.dll

Дополнительные сведения: Перед использованием свойства ItemsSource семейство Items должно быть пустым.

Comment: Ага, вы забыли написать код для переопределения шаблона. Обновил ответ применительно к `DataGrid`

Comment: но тогда выводятся обе колонки, отформатированная и неотформатированная

Comment: Ну так отключите автоформирование столбцов: `AutoGenerateColumns="False"`